# Converting dB vs frequency to V/sqrt(Hz)/ frequency

Tags: noise, spectrum-analyzer

I have taken noise data with a spectrum analyzer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem able to plot the noise in the units of V/Sqrt(Hz) over frequency (Hz).

What I have acquired instead is dB vs frequency. I know the measurement bandwidth (100Hz), the resolution (# of data points) and reference power (10 dBm).

Is it possible to convert my data into the units of (V/Sqrt(Hz))?

Comment: What's the model of the spectrum analyzer?

Comment: @qrk fieldfox microwave analyzer n9918a.  It's handheld, so i expected it to be limited.

Answer (score 2):

Default for this instrument is measuring in \$dBm\$ (dB referenced to 1mW at 50 ohms). Page 87 in the manual shows how to set the Y-axis to various units. However, it looks like this analyzer doesn't support spectral density.

To go from \$dBm\$ to \$dBV\$ (dB relative to 1 volt) in a 50 ohm system:
$$ dBV = dBm - 13 $$
To go from \$dBV\$ to \$dBV/Hz\$:
$$ dBV/Hz = dBV - 10 \; log(noise\_bandwidth) $$

To go from \$dBV/Hz\$ to \$ V/\sqrt{Hz}\$:
$$V/\sqrt{Hz} = 10^{dBV/Hz \over {20}}$$

The problem is figuring out your **noise bandwidth**, which is **not** the same as **resolution bandwidth** unless the filter is a brick wall. Analyzers that give a spectral density readout know the relationship between resolution BW and noise BW. As a first guess, you can use the resolution bandwidth  as your noise bandwidth if the bin filter is steep walled. You should actually calibrate your analyzer against a known noise source if you desire accuracy to figure out the ratio between *noise_bandwidth* and *resolution_bandwidth*.

Another thing is the **Video filter**. The Video filter alters noise measurements. Again, you need to use a calibrated noise source to determine the effects of video bandwidth. As a guess, I would make the video filter bandwidth as wide as possible (you need to experiment to understand this instrument). The analyzers I use, I disable video filtering for accurate noise measurements.